# *this (Return reference to the calling object) does not return changed object's value in that function

Tags: c++, return, this-pointer

Suppose there are two object : num1 , num2 each store integer number of 5 .

I want to add both object's value using non member function so result is : 10 .

But THE OUTPUT show value : 5 .

Is there any error in class member function or *this pointer ?

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Person.h"  
using namespace std ;

int main(){
    Person num1 ;
    Person num2 ;

    num1.InValueCapture(5) ;
    num2.InValueCapture(5) ;

    add(num1,num2);   //non class member function  : num1+num2 expecting result : 10           
    
    cout << "THE OUTPUT : " << num1.GetValueCapture() << endl; //but now we get 5 
    return 0 ;
}
```

Person.h

```
#ifndef PERSON.H
#define PERSON.H

struct Person{
private:
    int value_capture ;
public:

    int InValueCapture(int value){
        value_capture = value ;
    }

    int GetValueCapture() const {
        return value_capture ;
    }

    //adding two data
    Person& combine(const Person &Rdata)
    {
        value_capture += Rdata.value_capture ;
        std::cout << "value capture : " << value_capture <<std::endl; // use to check value inside DataSum.value_capture

        return *this ;
    }
};



Person add(const Person &Ldata , const Person &Rdata)       //nonmember function 
{
    Person DataSum = Ldata;
    DataSum.combine(Rdata);  // add Rdata to Ldata , call class function combine
    return DataSum ;        //
}

#endif
```

Thank you for your guidance , appreciate your help .

Comment: Your add function is modifying and returning the `DataSum` object you created in it.  You need to modify `LData` or `RData` if you want to see the changes applied to the object you passed to the function.

Comment: Same situation: `int add(const int& a, const int& b) { int sum = a; sum += b; return sum; }`. Do you see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments are liars:

```
DataSum.combine(Rdata);  // add Rdata to Ldata , call class function combine
```

This does not "add Rdata to Ldata". You are calling a method of `DataSum` which is a copy of `LData`. Modifiying the copy has no effect on the original `LData`. Don't make a copy:

```
void add(Person &Ldata , const Person &Rdata)       //nonmember function 
{
    Ldata.combine(Rdata);  // add Rdata to Ldata , call class function combine
}
```

Actually I am not 100% sure what the function is supposed to do. If you want to modify the first parameter you cannot pass it as `const` reference. If you want to not modify it passing `const` reference is fine, then you can return the result, but thats already what your function does, just that you ignore the returned value. I removed the return to make it more clear that the function modifies its first parameter. Though, now the caller can as well call `combine` directly.

Comment: This won't work because `combine` is, rightly, a non-`const` member function so you can't call it if `Ldata` is a `const Person&`. The actual problem is they seem to expect `add` to be mutating its arguments, instead of using the return value they've written.

Comment: @NathanPierson realized that and removed the `const`. Now I am not sure if it should return a reference or a copy...

Comment: If it's actually supposed to mutate its left hand side, I don't see an immediately obvious reason for it to return anything at all. But then I don't see why you'd write a non-member `add` function that mutates its left hand side instead of `operator+=` or something.

Comment: @NathanPierson I suppose this is just an "issue" encountered while practicing and trying out different things. The free function is rather useless when one can call `combine` directly

Comment: Thank you , problem solve by remove const .

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Person add(const Person &Ldata , const Person &Rdata)
```

to

```
[[nodiscard]] Person add(const Person &Ldata , const Person &Rdata)
```

`add` is a "pure" function, in that it returns the sum of L and R.

It does not modify either.

Once you do this:

```
add(num1,num2);   //non class member function  : num1+num2 expecting result : 10
```

this results in a compiler error, as you are doing the equivalent of `x+y` then discarding the result.

```
num1 = add(num1, num2);
```

does what you want.

A function called `add` should **not** modify its arguments.

Possibly you should embrace operations.  Change `combine` to:

```
//adding two data
Person& operator+=(const Person &Rdata)&
{
    value_capture += Rdata.value_capture ;
    std::cout << "value capture : " << value_capture <<std::endl; // use to check value inside DataSum.value_capture

    return *this ;
}
```

and `add` to:

```
// notice we take Ldata **by value**, making a copy
[[nodiscard]] Person operator+(Person Ldata, const Person &Rdata)  {
  Ldata += Rdata;
  return Ldata;
}
```

your `main` code then becomes:

```
num1 = num1+num2;
```

or

```
num1 += num2;
```

both of which are very clear in what they should do.